# Get changing patterns with grep -- R

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I want to grade several students exams using an answer key with grep. So for example, the student's answers were

```
A B B C E D D
```

and the key is

```
A D B C E CD ABD
```

I want to check to see if the student's answers are found in the corresponding position in the answer key (multiple letters indicate "or" not "and". So "C" or "D"). How would I got about that using grep?

Comment: What should the output look like? And what did you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or we can use `Map/mapply` from `base R`

```
unname(mapply(grepl, answer, key))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

#### data

```
answer <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "E", "D", "D") 
key <- c("A", "D", "B", "C", "E", "CD", "ABD")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `map2_lgl` function from the `purrr` package with `grepl`. `TRUE` means the answer found to be matched with the key. `FALSE` means no match.

```
# Create example of answer and key
answer <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "E", "D", "D") 
key <- c("A", "D", "B", "C", "E", "CD", "ABD")

# Load packages
library(purrr)

# Check if answer is in key
map2_lgl(answer, key, ~grepl(.x, .y))
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```